# How do I prevent page refresh and make it to remain in same tab section after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, tabs

I use a multi-purpose and functional form script which I can call via embed or page load into a mltiple tabbed design.

Each tab has a different form embedded and together with form validation etc, I have it working perfectly. The problem is, when I submit a form in tab 1, it will revert to the save state of the last tab instead of the tab with the submitted form.
I am using FSContact Forms - (http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/) Php Version and SkyTabs - (http://voky.com.ua/showcase/sky-tabs/.
I am very new to php and total noob to programming.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: basic solution: add a hidden input to each form which represents the selected tab, when the document is loaded (`window.onload` or `$(document).ready()`) if that value is present then select the appropriate tab using JS, else let it be on it's initial state

Comment: Hi Abdo, Thank you for your prompt response. Could you tell me where to put the (window.onload or $(document).ready()) . Would that be in the tab(s) or the form? Sorry if it's a silly question but I'm not sure how to implement your answer. Thank you

Comment: the hidden input should be in the form so that it can be submitted to the server (along with the rest of data) and re-used during the page loading, ignore the `window.onload` event, just check for the passed tab value and add the proper css class to the selected tab

Comment: Hi Abdo, Thanks again. I did as suggested but I'm afraid, it's reverting back to the last saved state tab instead of the one firing the form input. I will keep trying and adapting. In the mean time, it will be helpful to me and I'm sure to others if anyone or youself can demonstrate this with some sort of code snippet. Thank you for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by **"it's reverting back to the last saved state tab "** , can you edit your answer and post the code that you have tried?